# How to determine rate law for a reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

I am having trouble understanding this problem.

> A proposed mechanism for the decomposition of $\ce{N2O5}$ is as follows
>
> \begin{align}
> \ce{N2O5 &->[$k_1$]NO2 + NO3}          &&\text{(slow step)} \tag1\\
> \ce{NO2 + NO3 &->[$k_2$]NO2 + O2 + NO} &&\text{(fast step)} \tag2\\
> \ce{NO + N2O5 &->[$k_3$]3NO2}          &&\text{(fast step)} \tag3\\
> \end{align}
> What is the rate law predicted by this mechanism?
>
> A. $\quad \text{Rate} = k[\ce{N2O5}]$
> B. $\quad \text{Rate} = k[\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]$
> C. $\quad \text{Rate} = k[\ce{NO}][\ce{N2O5}]$
> D. $\quad \text{Rate} = k[\ce{N2O5}][\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]$
> E. $\quad \text{Rate} = k[\ce{N2O5}]^2$

I can determine the rate law for each individual reaction:

\begin{align}
\text{Rate} &= k_1[\ce{N2O5}] \tag{1'}\\
\text{Rate} &= k_2[\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]\tag{2'}\\
\text{Rate} &= k_3[\ce{NO}][\ce{N2O5}]\tag{3'}
\end{align}

But I am having trouble understanding how to incorporate all of this reaction rates into one complete reaction rate.

Do I multiply all the rates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the system is described, we can suppose $k_1 \ll k_2$ ans $k1 \ll k_3$, as Martin correctly noted and I have omitted to explicitly mention.

For such cases, we can consider for intermediate products to be in a steady state, i.e. $\frac {\mathrm{d}[A]}{\mathrm{d}t} \simeq 0$. So the rate of their creation is about equal to the rate of there destruction.

E.g. the rate of $\ce{NO3}$ production in reaction (1) is the same as the rate of its consumption in the reaction (2). Similarly, the rate of $\ce{NO}$ production in the reaction (2) is the same as the rate of its consumption in the reaction (3)

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO3}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_1 [\ce{N2O5}] - k_2 [\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]=0 \tag{1}$$

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_2 [\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]- k_3 [\ce{NO}][\ce{N2O5}]=0 \tag{2}$$

Then try to express concenrations of intermediate products as function of  concentration of reagents and final products.

$$[\ce{NO3}] = \frac{k_1 [\ce{N2O5}]}{k_2 [\ce{NO2}]} \tag{3}$$

$$ \ce{[NO}] = \frac{ k_2 [\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}] }{k_3 [\ce{N2O5}]} \tag{4}$$

$$ \ce{[NO}] = \frac{ k_2 [\ce{NO2}]\left( \frac{k_1 [\ce{N2O5}]}{k_2 [\ce{NO2}]} \right) }{k_3 [\ce{N2O5}]}=\frac{  k_1 [\ce{N2O5}]  }{k_3 [\ce{N2O5}]}=\frac{k_1}{k_3} \tag{5}$$

From (5) and  (2):

$$ k_2 [\ce{NO2}][\ce{NO3}]= k_1[\ce{N2O5}] \tag{6}$$

$$ [\ce{NO3}]= \frac{k_1[\ce{N2O5}]}{k_2 [\ce{NO2}]} \tag{7}$$

$$\frac {\mathrm{d}[\ce{NO2}]}{\mathrm{d}t} = k_1 [\ce{N2O5}] + 3 \cdot k_3 [\ce{NO}][\ce{N2O5}] = \\ 
k_1 [\ce{N2O5}] + 3 \cdot k_1 [\ce{N2O5}] = k [\ce{N2O5}] \tag{8}$$

---

**So the answer is A.**

Comment: How does eq(4) come?, from eq (5), you say that concentration of NO is fixed!?

Comment: Directly from (2)